# ng-view inside ng-controller strange behaviour with refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've this code:

```
<body ng-controller="CoreCtrl">

  <div ng-cloak>

    <!-- NavBar -->
    <div ng-include="'/app/core/navbar.html'"></div>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Main views -->
     <div ng-view></div>
   </div>
 </div></body>
```

All works fine when I load the page the first time or go to the page clicking a link, but if I press refresh button in browser the page reload but the ng-view content does not show or load the controller for the view. Back button in browser also works fine, the problem only happends with refresh or intro in address bar.

Controllers for all views are defined in the first div of template like  and all routes and templates are defined in app.js config.

Any idea about this problem? Could be a problem of to have ng-view inside a div with ng-controller?

I could confirm but I think that with old angular versions the problem is missing. Currently I'm working with 1.5.8 version and ng-route html5 mode off.

Regards

Comment: Do you see any console error?

Comment: No, no errors are showed in console.

Comment: Nobody has an idea regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and the problem was that the page was waiting for an object to be sent to it. so when you click on a link to get to this page you send the data with it but when you refresh that object is empty so the data doesn't show up.

Please share how did you define this view(state) in your app and I can give you more detailed answer.

Comment: This is my definition of routes:   `$routeProvider.when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
        access: userRoles.guest
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
        access: userRoles.guest
      })
      .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        access: userRoles.operator
      });`